# How do I set the properties or fields of the object dynamically in flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3

I have an array containing names lets say,

```
var myArray:Array=new Array("name1","name2","name3");
```

Now I want to use the array values as the object properties by iterating through the array
I meant I want the object to have name1,name2,name3 as the properties,

```
var myObject:Object=new object();
for(var i:int=0; i<myArray.length; i++){
myObject[myArray[i]]="something";
}
```

but this does not give me the required result,
it sets the object property as myArray[i] i.e, whatever I give inside the square braces is taken as a string in this case.I want the output to be,

```
myObject[name1]="something"
myObject[name2]="something" 
myObject[name3]="something"
```

but instead it gives the output as

```
myObject[myArray[i]]="something"
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I fully understand, but I think you've accomplished your goal.

In the debugger, I see:

[image: Debugger]

Was this not what you want?

I believe what you've stated is equivalent.

Comment: You can also define dynamic objects in different ways, like:

var myObject:Object = {name1: "something", name2: "something", name3: "something"};

Then iteration property names / values using for() and for each() patterns.